# Need help setting up CORS on tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat, cors

I'm rather confused right now on how to get CORS to work correctly on my Tomcat server. I have an application that offers a REST API. This API works just fine via testing with a Chrome app called Advanced Rest Client. Here is where I'm getting confused...

1. Do I need to edit the web.xml file for the entire Tomcat server or just the one in the specific web app I'm working with?
2. Why does my call work via Advanced Rest Client (which is a web app in a browser) and not via my web page?

I can offer any information you would like to help better describe this issue. This is one of my first posts here so please excuse the lack of any expected information. If you want to see the call or the filter I'm placing or the javascript I'm using to make the call please just ask. I'm just not sure what is needed to help debunk something like this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to edit the web.xml file for the entire Tomcat server or just the one in the specific web app I'm working with?

Depends what you are up to. If you edit the global web.xml, you are of course enabling CORS for every URL pattern matching the filter definition. Say if you insert the following:

```
     <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>
```

Then all AJAX calls going to http://myhost.mydomain/myapp/* will be CORS-enabled. You can also use [this filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html) to restrict CORS to only one WAR file - advantage of course: you don't have to edit the global web.xml file

> Why does my call work via Advanced Rest Client (which is a web app in a browser) and not via my web page?

Impossible to say without logs of the request/response communication, but most likely this Advanced Rest Client is trusted and therefore does not need to do CORS calls (after all, it is not loaded from site A and tries to access site B via AJAX, but explicitly installed by you, the user). You could find out in the Chrome Dev tools: look if there are `Origin: http://foo.example` headers for every GET/POST-request. If yes, then it's CORS, if no then not.

This paragraph from the [Chrome extensions developer page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) indicates this:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. **Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin**, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.